# Store rows of DataFrame with certain value in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like:

| id | country | city | amount | duplicated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | France | Paris | 200 | 1 |
| 2 | France | Paris | 200 | 1 |
| 3 | France | Lyon | 50 | 2 |
| 4 | France | Lyon | 50 | 2 |
| 5 | France | Lyon | 50 | 2 |

And I would like to store a list per distinct value in duplicated, like:

list 1

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "country": "France",
        "city": "Paris",
        "amount": 200,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "country": "France",
        "city": "Paris",
        "amount": 200,
    }
  ]
```

list 2

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "country": "France",
        "city": "Lyon",
        "amount": 50,
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "country": "France",
        "city": "Lyon",
        "amount": 50,
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "country": "France",
        "city": "Lyon",
        "amount": 50,
    }
  ]
```

I tried filtering duplicates with

```
df[df.duplicated(['country','city','amount', 'duplicated'], keep = False)]
```

but it just returns the same df.

Comment: Does your actual data have a `duplicated` column like in your sample data or no?

Comment: @It_is_Chris yes, I just removed it from output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
lst = (df.groupby(['country', 'city', 'amount'])  # or .groupby('duplicated')
         .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
         .tolist())
```

Output:

```
>>> lst
[[{'id': 3,
   'country': 'France',
   'city': 'Lyon',
   'amount': 50,
   'duplicated': 2},
  {'id': 4,
   'country': 'France',
   'city': 'Lyon',
   'amount': 50,
   'duplicated': 2},
  {'id': 5,
   'country': 'France',
   'city': 'Lyon',
   'amount': 50,
   'duplicated': 2}],
 [{'id': 1,
   'country': 'France',
   'city': 'Paris',
   'amount': 200,
   'duplicated': 1},
  {'id': 2,
   'country': 'France',
   'city': 'Paris',
   'amount': 200,
   'duplicated': 1}]]
```

Another solution if you want a dict indexed by `duplicated` key:

```
data = {k: v.to_dict('records') for k, v in df.set_index('duplicated').groupby(level=0)}
```

```
>>> data[1]
[{'id': 1, 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris', 'amount': 200},
 {'id': 2, 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris', 'amount': 200}]

>>> data[2]
[{'id': 3, 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Lyon', 'amount': 50},
 {'id': 4, 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Lyon', 'amount': 50},
 {'id': 5, 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Lyon', 'amount': 50}]
```

Comment: Yes this is the better solution, worked perfectly @Corralien. Will accept this as answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: one thing I noticed while applying, is that it reverts the order of the data frame and stores the lists in descending time order. Why doesn't it keep the ascending order the data frame has?

Comment: Use `sort=False` as parameter of `groupby`. Maybe it can solve the problem. However, there is no mention of time in your dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [DataFrame.to_dict('records')](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to make your lists:

```
list_1 = df[df['duplicated'] == 1].to_dict('records')
list_1 = df[df['duplicated'] == 2].to_dict('records')
```

Or for an arbitrary number of values in the column, you can make a dict:

```
result = {}
for value in df['duplicated'].unique():
    result[value] = df[df['duplicated'] == value].to_dict('records')
```

Comment: I tried and this works, thanks. Still not the full solution as there’s a big number of duplicated values so I’ll need to iterate through them I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Updated with better solution